# How to turn on Hardware Virtualization on Late 2013 MacBook Pro (for Windows 8.1 using Boot Camp)?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, virtualization

I am trying to turn on Hardware Virtualization for my new MacBook Pro for Windows 8.1 setup using Boot Camp.

I have searched online and I know that we can not just go to the BIOS like windows and change settings. Unfortunately, most of the solution I have come across are for Parallels or VMs.

Can anyone kindly let me know how to enable Hardware Virtualization on MBP for Windows 8.1 installed using Boot Camp?

Comment: Or perhaps you have Hyper-V installed :( see here: http://superuser.com/questions/866962/why-does-virtualbox-only-have-32-bit-option-no-64-bit-option-on-windows-7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hardware virtualization to turn on or off like on Wintel PCs.

That switch and many other BIOS switches are there because (at least in part) the hardware manufacturers don't make the hardware AND software, like Apple does.

It is always on in any Mac that has a processor that supports virtualization. Pretty much any Mac in the last several years does so you are good to go with this one.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. My only concern was that Visual Studio told me that the hardware virtualization was off.

Comment: Under task manager,  there should be an field telling you if virtualization is enabled. It's in full task manager,  under processor tab...

Comment: Wrong answer. `There is no hardware virtualization to turn on or off like on Wintel PCs.` is flat out wrong. Silicon features can be disabled via BIOS or UEFI - which is what's happening in Apple's broken bootcamp mode.

Comment: This answer is 100% incorrect.  Macbook Bootcamp is broken and sometimes turns it off.

Comment: It answered the OPs question sufficiently. Regardless of what is or is not "broken" on BootCamp this (I assume) sufficiently an answer that he/she was happy with. I have learned in IT it is not so much about being absolutely right or wrong, it's about fixing the issue. I guess this fixed the issue. The other answers suffice to expand and enhance...

Answer (score 43):

It sounds like you're running into the same issue I did, where after booting into Windows the VT-x shows as 'Disabled' in Task Manager.

Not sure how or why, but after going into

- OS X
- System Preferences
- Target Disk
- Select the **BOOTCAMP** disk as the
  startup disk

Everything was well after that and I could happily use Hyper-V, even from a cold boot.

If I cold booted using the <kbd>Options</kbd>-key, and then selecting **Windows**, VT-x was disabled in Task Manager.

Go figure. Could some Mac genius out there explain this one?

Comment: do you meant Startup or Target Disk mode in the startup panel

Comment: Mac "genius" will tell you you're using an unintended software with their hardware. Honest (something Apple should search for definition) answer would be - firmware bug which apple can't properly fix since 2008 (http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=821551).

Comment: It was the Startup Disk for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wasted nearly two hours before I found your answer.

Comment: This thread explains that you have to boot using the CSM-BIOS layer. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6720461?tstart=0 ; In addition it also provides a command line to permanently fix this problem. First use `diskutil list` to work out Windows partition, then `sudo /usr/sbin/bless --device /dev/disk0s4 --setBoot --legacy --legacydrivehint /dev/disk0`

Comment: Chui Tey comment worked howewer It was needed to disable system integrity protection as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932961/osx-10-11-el-capitan-setting-boot-device-property-not-working

Comment: These instructions didn't work for me on a 2012 MacBook Pro. I went into System Preferences and clicked "Target Disk Mode", but that didn't do anything. Things have probably changed on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6.

Comment: This worked for me while my iMac was on Mojave, then after I upgraded to Catalina, it's no longer needed! Virtualisation is enabled via simple Option- key boot to Windows

Answer (score 27):

EDIT: I found a better way to get this working instead of the boot dance originally suggested (it's below for reference). Basically set `enable_and_lock_vmx true` in rEFInd and that's it. Details below ...

## Suggested method

1. Disable macOS System Integrity Protection/SIP (Reboot Mac, hold down Command + R keys, at "OS X Utilities Utilities" pick "Terminal" menu item -> type in terminal `csrutil disable; reboot`)
2. Back inside macOS after the reboot, get [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and extract it anywhere (desktop, downloads etc)
3. Open a terminal window, cd to where you extracted it and edit via `sudo nano refind/refind.conf-sample`
4. Uncomment `enable_and_lock_vmx` and set to `true` i.e. the whole line should read `enable_and_lock_vmx true`. **<= This is what really fixes the issue!**
5. **[optional]** While here, change the timeout to something quick, like 4 or 5 i.e. `timeout 4`
6. Install rEFInd by running `./refind-install` from terminal. The sample config you edited is used as the installed config.
7. **[optional]** Enable SIP again. Follow #1 above but run `csrutil enable; reboot` instead

This method is very smooth - it works on normal as well as encrypted disks (FileVault2, VeraCrypt or BitLocker) and really takes a few minutes to install. Best of all, it works in every reboot.

## Old method

None of the other methods worked for me, especially since my Windows 10 was Bitlocker encrypted i.e. it doesn't show up in `Startup Disks` to chose to reboot to. The steps below work though

1. Power off

   Not just a hard reboot; **fully powered off**; as in '*count to 10 when off*' off
2. Power on and Boot to OS X desktop

   This process loads virtualization properly. In my case, I had to hold `option` and select OS X, enter my FileVault password (my OS X is encrypted) and then wait to boot into OS X desktop.
3. Reboot to Windows

   Soft reboot via the Apple menu i.e. top left Apple icon => restart. During bootup select Windows/Bootcamp (via the option key). My Windows was Bitlocker encrypted, so I entered the disk password, booted to Windows, entered Windows password, landed on Windows 10 desktop. This time Hyper-V was present and functional!

I'm putting this here for future reference but I hope Apple actually fixes their Bootcamp boot process. It's been broken for 8 years now and the above hackery is ridiculous for a $3000 machine and when Bootcamp is an officially supported Mac feature.

Comment: PERFECT SOLUTION. Congrats 4 that.

Comment: I only have one partition with Windows 10 on my MacBook (MacBookPro11,2 - 2014 - Core i7 2.2), so I can't do the steps on OS X.  Any idea on how to do this on Windows only?

Comment: Here is more detailed step-by-step instruction for newer versions of MacOS X (El Capitan in my case) https://dea.nbird.com.au/2017/02/24/enabling-vt-x-on-mac-book-air-in-bootcamp/ with some optional ways (e.g. using Windows only without MacOS)

Comment: For GRUB users, adding `wrmsr 0x3a 0x05` to grub.cfg achieves the same as `enable_and_lock_vmx true` in rEFInd.

Comment: Awesome!! Confirmed to work in Big Sur running on a mid-2015 Macbook pro

Answer (score 7):

It seems that if you boot directly to Windows it doesn't work, but if you boot to OS X and switch to Windows, it works. Or you can boot to Windows, change to OS X and go back to Windows again.

Comment: This worked for me. 
1. boot into OS X and I ran ```docker run hello-world``` to ensure docker was working correctly. It was
2. Restart and hold the option key to bring up the option to book into Windows
3. Select Windows. I ran ```docker run hello-world``` to ensure docker was working correctly. It was.

Comment: This is what worked for me.  It seems that the MacBook Pro needs to boot into OSX to enable virtualization.  After that, a soft restart into Windows will have virtualization enabled.  I have a mid-2015 15" MacBook Pro with i7 and Windows 10 Pro with Anniversary Update.

Comment: I only know of cold-booting into WIN on my MAC by using the Options-key. When I instead boot to MAC first, how do I then switch to WIN on a BootCamp?

Comment: On preferences, there is a boot disk section that allows you to choose a partition to boot

Answer (score 2):

I tried with and without holding alt key down, from Mac OS to Windows and the other way.

The Hyper-V installation begins and asks for a reboot, and during starting up of windows then 2nd step of the installation failed and rolled back.

Today I bought thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter, plugged it, installed Hyper-V and after reboot I could use it.
Even when I unplug the adapter.

So it seams Hyper-V need some sort of Ethernet Adapter installed.

Comment: The 'thunderbolt to ethernet adapter' trick for getting hyper-v to work does NOT work with an 2015 iMac + Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

After I installed rEFInd to triple boot my MF839 Macbook (Win10, Ubuntu, OSX), to enable Virtualization on Windows 10, first I boot to OSX, then when it's login screen appear, I hit the restart button so the mac restart again then I choose Windows 10 from rEFInd.

Comment: Which mac were you using?

Answer (score 1):

I had tried all the various boot / reboot combinations and nothing worked until I added the Thunderbolt to Ethernet adaptor. The next time I started up the Windows Boot Camp partition I could enable Hyper V.