# MacBook Pro 2015 BootCamp HyperV Support is yes but Virtualization: disabled

Tags: bootcamp, windows, virtualization

I am unable to get the the Virtualizarion enabled on my bootcamp of windows 10.
Using the boot into IOS then switch to windows trick I was able to get hyper-v support to "yes" but I haven't figured out a way to enable the virtualization.
I have reinstalled the Hyper-V management tools and that seems to have no affect.

Any other ideas would be so appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run `msinfo32` and report the Hyper-V lines (bottom of right pane)

Comment: @user71659 added report for Hyper-V

Comment: Try https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234819/71659

Comment: yeah I saw that one I want to continue to use boot camp. After some further digging it looks like Hyper-V is not supported on new-ish macs. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/281599/hyper-v-in-windows-10-on-macbook-pro. Looks like I may be out of luck.