# how to turn on hardware virtualization on Macbook pro with BootCamp with no OSX

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, partition, virtualization

I haven't been able to turn on hardware virtualization on a Mac with BootCamp (Windows 10).
All the solutions I have found say that I need to restart and choose OS X ( including [How to turn on Hardware Virtualization on Late 2013 MacBook Pro (for Windows 8.1 using Boot Camp)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120361/how-to-turn-on-hardware-virtualization-on-late-2013-macbook-pro-for-windows-8-1)), but my problem is that BootCamp is the only partition there is my machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn on Hardware Virtualization on Late 2013 MacBook Pro (for Windows 8.1 using Boot Camp)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120361/how-to-turn-on-hardware-virtualization-on-late-2013-macbook-pro-for-windows-8-1)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I even mentioned that question one in the text

Comment: What year/model is your Mac? there was a switch in firmware 2012 or 2013

Comment: Not sure about the exact model, it's a 15-inch retina display. Is that something you can check from Bootcamp?

Comment: The processor should be enough to tell

Comment: It's an Intel Core i7-4770HQ @ 2.20 Ghz 2.20 Ghz

Comment: seems it was released on 2014 https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/core_i7/i7-4770hq

Comment: You can get recovery mode command+r. Power off machine.  Hold down command+r; power one.  Continue holder til you see something.   This is a variant of macOS.  Don't know if it sets this bit or not. There is boot of of apple sever too. To manually start up from macOS Recovery over the Internet, press and hold Option-Command-R or Shift-Option-Command-R at startup  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

Comment: If that don't work, you can install macOS on an external drive in recovery  mode.  Hold down the option key to select which OS to boot.

Comment: 2014... Could be either BIOS or EFI, check using msinfo command on windows. You either need to bless the bootcamp partition, or you need a custom boot loader that will enable hardware guest on startup... It might be less of a headache to just have a Mac installation on your machine, for example firmware updates arent

Comment: installed through the windows version of apple software update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting on Internet recovery mode and just restarting from there (nothing else done) then virtualization got enabled in BootCamp!

Comment: Yes, if you choose startup disk, that should work.. But I'm wondering, does it stick? A little hit and miss ime, if you ever suffer a crash and find the feature is disabled remember to do this again

Comment: it does not stick. Annoying